# How to match all words but one?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match expressions that start with PRE and end with PRE. I'm looking for a lazy match, that is the ending PRE in the matched expression should be the first one found after the starting PRE.
I was trying to achieve this with a negative lookahead regex, testing on RegExr:

Regex:

```
PRE(\w|\s)+(?!PRE)
```

Expression to match:

```
PRE erp PRE edas PRE
```

The expression above is matched in full by the given regex, while I had expected only to match PRE erp PRE.
Please suggest a regex that lazily matches expression starting and ending with PRE.

Comment: This should return how many matches? 2?

Comment: Is case significant?  That is, would `pre` or `pRe` (for example) be treated as a delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"(PRE)(.*?)(PRE)"
```

This works for me in my (C#) code, returning one match, PRE erp PRE.

```
        var codeBlocks = Regex.Matches("PRE erp PRE edas PRE", "(PRE)(.*?)(PRE)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        MessageBox.Show("Matches found: " + codeBlocks.Count.ToString() + "\nMatch: " + codeBlocks[0].Value);
```

Comment: you should leave the ignorecase flag away

Answer (score 5):

Supposed your language support lazy matching (if it supports look-around, I suppose it also supports lazy quantifier):

```
PRE(.*?)PRE
```

As this answer may be wrong, please specify your language next time. Regex has different set of features for different the languages.

Comment: That's what I came up with as well.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
(?<=PRE)(.+?)(?=PRE)
```

http://regexr.com?31bc5